# Storing only specific values in an array from another array

Tags: vba, excel

The goal of this sub is to run through an existing array where all values stored in the array slots before the array slot containing the String "Score" are useless, and all the ones after this slot and before the slot containing the String "Why?" are meaningful. So the array could look like this:

```
IQRngRef(0).Value2(1) = "Pineapple"
IQRngRef(0).Value2(2) = "Apple"
IQRngRef(0).Value2(3) = "Lemons"
IQRngRef(0).Value2(4) = "Score"
IQRngRef(0).Value2(5) = "23"
IQRngRef(0).Value2(6)= "45"
IQRngRef(0).Value2(7) = "333"
IQRngRef(0).Value2(8) = "Why?"
IQRngRef(0).Value2(9) = "77"
IQRngRef(0).Value2(10) = "60"
```

I want to then store only the values {23|45|333} into an array roleArray(). The Following is what I came up with, but I'm sure there's an easier/ more efficient way.

Also, this is giving me `run-time error 451 property let procedure not defined and property get procedure did not return an object` on this line: `roleIdentifier = IQRngRef(0).Value2(rowIterator)` and I can't figure out how to fix it.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

```
Private Sub IdentifyRolesAndScoresRows(ByRef IQRngRef As Variant, ByVal rowNumb As Long)
    Dim rowIterator As Long
    Dim roleIdentifier As String

    Do Until roleIdentifier = "Score"
        For rowIterator = 1 To rowNumb
            roleIdentifier = IQRngRef(0).Value2(rowIterator)
        Next rowIterator
    Loop

    Dim roleArray(1 To 10) As String
    Dim roleArrayCount As Long
    Do Until roleIdentifier = "Why?"
        For rowIterator = rowIterator + 1 To rowNumb
            roleIdentifier = IQRngRef(0).Value2(rowIterator)
            roleArrayCount = roleArrayCount + 1
            roleArray(roleArrayCount) = roleIdentifier
        Next rowIterator
    Loop
End Sub
```

This is the code that fills `IQRngRef()`

```
Private Sub CaptureIQRefsLocally(ByVal ShRef As Worksheet, ByVal rowNumb As Long, ByVal colNumb As Long, ByRef IQRef As Variant, ByRef IQRngref As Variant)
    'capture IQ references in arrays. Values for column titles in IQRef and full column Ranges in IQRngRef.
    Dim iCol As Long
    Dim alignIQNumbToArrayNumb As Long
    With ShRef
        For iCol = 1 To colNumb
            alignIQNumbToArrayNumb = iCol - 1
            Set IQRngref(alignIQNumbToArrayNumb) = .Range(.Cells(1, iCol), .Cells(rowNumb, iCol))
            IQRef(alignIQNumbToArrayNumb) = .Cells(1, iCol).Value
            'IsThisaKeyIQ IQRngref, IQRef
        Next iCol
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: how is `IQRngRef` actually declared and filled in the calling sub?

Comment: IQRngRef is a dimmed as a Variant and it takes in ranges, hence the `.Value2()` so `IQRngRef(0)` is a Variant/Object/Range and `Value2(1)` is a Variant/String

Comment: please, show the code that fills it

Comment: I updated the post above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you can adapt this for your particular situation.

```
Sub x()

Dim v(1 To 10), n1 As Long, n2 As Long, v1, i As Long

v(1) = "Pineapple"
v(2) = "Apple"
v(3) = "Lemons"
v(4) = "Score"
v(5) = "23"
v(6) = "45"
v(7) = "333"
v(8) = "Why?"
v(9) = "77"
v(10) = "60"

n1 = Application.Match("Score", v, 0)
n2 = Application.Match("Why?", v, 0)

v1 = Application.Index(v, Evaluate("ROW(" & n1 + 1 & ":" & n2 - 1 & ")"))

For i = LBound(v1) To UBound(v1)
    MsgBox v1(i, 1)
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to work with "Variant array of 1D Variant arrays" (i.e. Variant/Variant) and then slice these latter by means of Application.Index function as per [This Link](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/927644-split-array-vba-2.html)

so, first change `CaptureIQRefsLocally()` sub as follows:

```
Private Sub CaptureIQRefsLocally(ByVal ShRef As Worksheet, ByVal rowNumb As Long, ByVal colNumb As Long, ByRef IQRef As Variant, ByRef IQRngref As Variant)
    'capture IQ references in arrays. Values for column titles in IQRef and full column Ranges values in IQRngRef.
    Dim iCol As Long
    Dim alignIQNumbToArrayNumb As Long
    With ShRef
        For iCol = 1 To colNumb
            alignIQNumbToArrayNumb = iCol - 1
            IQRngref(alignIQNumbToArrayNumb) = Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(1, iCol), .Cells(rowNumb, iCol)).Value) ' make an 1D array out of range values and store it in current 'IQRngref' element
            IQRef(alignIQNumbToArrayNumb) = .Cells(1, iCol).Value
            'IsThisaKeyIQ IQRngref, IQRef
        Next iCol
    End With
End Sub
```

and then change `IdentifyRolesAndScoresRows()` sub as follows:

```
Private Sub IdentifyRolesAndScoresRows(ByRef IQRngref As Variant, ByVal rowNumb As Long)
    Dim startIndex As Long, endIndex As Long

    startIndex = Application.Match("Score", IQRngref(0), 0)
    endIndex = Application.Match("Why?", IQRngref(0), 0)

    Dim roleArray As Variant

    roleArray = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(IQRngref(0), Evaluate("ROW(" & startIndex + 1 & ":" & endIndex - 1 & ")"))) ' from https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/927644-split-array-vba-2.html
End Sub
```

Comment: I ended up reading SJR's post and going with this: `Private Sub IdentifyRolesAndScoresRows(ByRef IQRngRef As Variant, ByVal rowNumb As Long)
    Dim scoreBound As Long
    scoreBound = Excel.Application.Match("Score", IQRngRef(0).Value2, 0)
    Dim whyBound As Long
    whyBound = Excel.Application.Match("Why?", IQRngRef(0).Value2, 0)
    
    Dim roleArray As Variant
    roleArray = Excel.Application.Index(IQRngRef(0).Value2, Evaluate("ROW(" & scoreBound + 1 & ":" & whyBound - 1 & ")"))
End Sub` It works fine now. Do you think there will be issues with what I did in the future?